# Is asleep in "to fall asleep" an adverb?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, parts-of-speech, linking-verbs

DK school dictionary says "asleep" in *to fall asleep* is an adverb.

Yet, according to https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/asleep

> **"Asleep" in *to fall asleep* is an adjective.**

To the best of my knowledge, the "fall" is a linking verb which requires a predicative complement. It seems that DK school dictionary made an error. Isn't it?

Comment: People can also "fall pregnant"; that supports the linking verb + adjective answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Cambridge online dictionary is wrong in this case; it actually is an adverb when used with the verb “fall”. “Asleep” means “into a state of sleep” when it’s part of the phrase “fall asleep.”

See: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/asleep

Comment: Could it be that American lexicographers differ fron British lexicographers? Oxford says that's an adjective. source:https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/asleep　Macmillan says that's an adjective　source:https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/asleep

Comment: That’s certainly possible. I can also see it making sense as an adjective. In the phrase “to become asleep” (if anyone would actually say that), “asleep” definitely seems like an adjective to me. “To fall asleep” is more ambiguous. Where was the DK dictionary published?

Comment: "To fall asleep" is like "to become angry", "to grow weary", or even "to fall ill". "Asleep", "angry", "weary", and "ill" are adjectives in these examples. I think you are correct about "to fall" being a linking verb, at least in the context of "falling asleep". "To become", and "to grow" are also linking verbs in these examples. (US and British style.)